# Turning selected pixels to black based on an HSV hue range

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, hsv

This snippet of code is part of a program that turns pixels to black in an opencv image based on an HSV hue range (here, 180-250).
Does somebody happen to understand why the code below raises the error **exceptions.AttributeError:'tuple' object has no attribute all** on the last line? 'image' is a numpy.ndarray (obtained with np.asarray(image[:,:]) from an opencv cvMat)

```
image=np.asarray(image[:,:])
hue=np.resize(image,(480,640,1))
hue[hue < 180]=0
hue[hue > 250]=0
hue2=np.resize(hue,(480,640,3))
image[np.where(hue2==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2)]=[0,0,0]
```

While the code

```
image=np.asarray(image[:,:])
image[np.where((np.not_equal(image,[0,0,0])).all(axis=2))]=[0,0,0]
```

works perfectly, since 'hue2' and 'image' are two numpy arrays of exact same dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like misplaced braces. It should be

```
image[np.where((hue2==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))]=[0,0,0]
```

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood the line format and went on searching for hours on this one :-)